# AutoHotKey В Zbrush

Tags: autohotkey

я Левша и хочу настроить горячие клавиши под левшу в Zbrush, но есть ряд проблем.

вот что прописано у меня

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ZBrush
Right::LCtrl
Up::LAlt
Left::LShift
Delete::W
End::E  
PgDn::R
Home::Q
Ins::T
PgUp::BS
Down & Numpad4::^Z
Down & Numpad6::^+Z
Down & Numpad1::+F
Down & Numpad3::+P
```

все работает кроме Ctrl Z и Ctrl Shift Z (назад, вперед) и кнопки E, R, W, Q, T **невоспринимаются **именно** программой**, *хотя скрипт работает и в поисковой строке или в блокноте эти буквы вписываются*
(**действия Ctrl Z не работает нигде**)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в заглавных буквах (Z, W, D) нужно было писать строчной (z,w,d) иначе добавлялась не нужная кнопка shift и в программе они не читались + ктрл з я писал не правильно, нужно зажимать ктрл код в итоге идеальный такой:

```
   Right::LCtrl
Up::LAlt
Left::LShift
Delete::w
End::e 
PgDn::r
Home::q
Ins::t
PgUp::bs
Down & Numpad4::Send ^{z}
Down & Numpad6::Send ^+{z}
Down & Numpad1::+f
Down & Numpad3::+p
```